# ServiceStack OrmLite PUT deletes all the fields except those are passed

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

ServiceStack OrmLite PUT deletes all the fields except those are passed

Answer (score 0):

You can use OrmLite's UpdateNonDefaults API and if you only want to update fields that have non-default values, however I would still be updating all fields for PUTs, if you only want to update partial fields I would use PATCH. Whilst POST's are typically used for creating (inserting) resources or other non-idempotent requests.

Comment: Thank you. I have used PATCH before. Do you think I can just replace 'PUT' as 'PATCH' then it will works or there is further work?

Comment: The method name has no effect on the impl, it's your job to decide on behaviour e.g by using the appropriate OrmLite API. But in terms of implementing PATCH method, yeah changing the name is all you'd need to do on the server, but I'd still prefer using PUT and updating all fields.

Comment: Hi, i tried UpdateNonDefaults and it works like a charm for now. Could you please clarify a bit what is this 'non default'? So a field with existing value and has no value passed in is considered a 'default'? So it doesn't get updated? A field a field with existing value BUT has value passed in is considered a 'non default'? And it gets updated? Sorry, my head just cannot get the name 'non default' and what it does (only update fields passed) wired together. Thanks.

Comment: @user5506787 non default values, it means non `default(T)` which is null for reference types or default value for value types.